# Extracting MySQLdb column values within Flask

Tags: flask, mysql-python

I am trying to program a simple dropdown where I do get data from the MySQLdb connection and cycle woth Flask through the resuls, but the data is not shown correctly. I have consulted and followed other posts yet in my case it does not work (no matter what I do).

Intended result:

```
    <option value="1">Appels</option>
    <option value="2">Bananas/option>
    <option value="3">Cherries</option>
    <option value="4">Peaches</option>
```

Actual result:

```
    <option value=""> (1, &#39;Appels&#39;) </option>
    <option value=""> (2, &#39;Bananas&#39;) </option>
    <option value=""> (3, &#39;Cherries&#39;) </option>
    <option value=""> (4, &#39;Peaches&#39;) </option>
```

I got the data in Flask from a MySQL database with MySQLdb with the following code:

```
    @app.route('/testbed', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
    def testbed():
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        fruit = cursor.execute("SELECT id, type FROM fruit")
        return render_template('testbed.html', fruit=cursor.fetchall())
```

The corresponding HTML code:

```
    <select name="fldFruitPicker" class="form-select form-select-sm">
    {% for type in fruit %}
    <option value="{{ id }}"> {{ type }} </option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your html to smth like this:

```
 <select name="fldFruitPicker" class="form-select form-select-sm">
 {% for type in fruit %}
 <option value="{{ type[0] }}"> {{ type[1] }} </option>
 {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

- Please, don't use `type` as variable name, it's reserved python word
- You can use `mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)` cursor initialization for dict as result. Then you can write not `type[0]`, but `type.id`  in your template. It will be more clear, I think.

Comment: Hi zt50tz,


First of all many thanks for the feedback! Coming back to the two points:


1) the word "type" was changed to "fruit_type", thank you for the suggestion


2) The part 'mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)' was included in the app.py but now it runs in the following error:


NameError: name 'MySQLdb' is not defined

Comment: Please, type `import MySQLdb` at the top of file that has this route and has cursor creation.